# MySQL Queries in one Json object

Tags: php, mysql

The goal is to return a json object, for a Javascript XMLHttpRequest.

The object returned would be (example):

```
[{"id": "6", "name": "Roger Coleman","start": "1612738800000", "end": "1613257200000", "color": "#FF0000"}, {"id": "7", "name": "Joe Jackson","start": "1615417200000", "end": "1618178399000", "color": "#0000FF"}]
```

The problem I'm facing is following: the "**color**" values comes from another table.
So I need to launch the first query:

```
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, name FROM table1 WHERE category='$category'
```

And for each name value returned in each row I need to launch another query to get the color from another table:

```
SELECT color from table2 WHERE name='$name'
```

How can I 'merge' the result of the two queries, so that I can return it in one json object to the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Read about `JOIN`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you can use a [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) clause. A join clause combines rows from two or more tables based on a common column which in your case is the `name` column.

The SQL to solve your problem is:

```
    SELECT id, start_date, end_date, table1.name AS name, color 
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
    WHERE category = "$category"
```

Note that in the SELECT clause I used `table1.name AS name` because the column `name` is present in both table and it will generate an error related to the duplicity of of the column `name`.